# jquery inserting blank row between each record in GridView

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am having issues with blank rows between each record in my GridView.  I suspect the problem lies in this code:

```
var row;
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);
            var company = xml.find("Company");
            if (row == null) {
                row = $("[id*=GridView1] tr:last-child").clone(true);
            }
            $("[id*=GridView1] tr").not($("[id*=GridView1] tr:first-child")).remove();
            if (company.length > 0) {
                $.each(company, function () {
                    var company = $(this);
                $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("LN").text());
                $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("FN").text());
                $("td", row).eq(2).html($(this).find("Company").text());
                $("td", row).eq(3).html($(this).find("City").text());
                $("td", row).eq(4).html($(this).find("State").text());
                $("td", row).eq(5).html($(this).find("sID").text());
                $("td", row).eq(6).html($(this).find("Status").text());
                $("td", row).eq(7).html($(this).find("DateAss").text());
                $("td", row).eq(8).html($(this).find("DateS").text());
                $("td", row).eq(9).html($(this).find("DateApp").text());
                $("td", row).eq(10).html($(this).find("P").text());
                $("td", row).eq(11).html($(this).find("T").text());
                $("td", row).eq(12).html($(this).find("N").text());
                $("td", row).eq(13).html($(this).find("CCID").text());
                $("[id*=GridView1]").append(row);
                row = $("[id*=GridView1] tr:last-child").clone(true);
                });

                var pager = xml.find("Pager");
                $(".Company").ASPSnippets_Pager({
                    ActiveCssClass: "current",
                    PagerCssClass: "pager",
                    PageIndex: parseInt(pager.find("PageIndex").text()),
                    PageSize: parseInt(pager.find("PageSize").text()),
                    RecordCount: parseInt(pager.find("RecordCount").text())
                });
                $(".Company").each(function () {
                    var searchPattern = new RegExp('(' + SearchTerm() + ')', 'ig');
                    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(searchPattern, "<span class = 'highlight'>" + SearchTerm() + "</span>"));
                });
            } else {
                var empty_row = row.clone(true);
                $("td:first-child", empty_row).attr("colspan", $("td", row).length);
                $("td:first-child", empty_row).attr("align", "center");
                $("td:first-child", empty_row).html("No records found for the search criteria.");
                $("td", empty_row).not($("td:first-child", empty_row)).remove();
                $("[id*=GridView1]").append(empty_row);
            }
        };
```

More specifically, I think the problem lies with the fact that the column named "Company" has no blank records.  When I change all the instances of "Company" and company in the above code to "LN" and ln (which does contain blank records) the GridView returns nothing.

Any advice would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Script

```
 function OnSuccess(response) {
            var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
            var xml = $(xmlDoc);

            var details = xml.find("Table1");          
            $("[id*=tblDetailData]").append('<tr>'+
                      '      <td></td>'+
                      '      <td></td>'+
                      '      <td></td>'+
                      '      <td></td>'+
                      '      <td></td>'+
                      '      <td></td>'+
                      '  </tr>');

            var row = $("[id*=tblDetailData] tr:last-child").clone(true);     

            $("[id*=tblDetailData] tr").not($("[id*=tblDetailData] tr:first-child")).remove();
            $.each(details, function () {  

                $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("DATE").text());
                $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("TYPE").text());
                $("td", row).eq(2).html($(this).find("ACTION").text());
                $("td", row).eq(3).html($(this).find("USERID").text());
                $("td", row).eq(4).html($(this).find("FIELD").text());
                $("td", row).eq(5).html($(this).find("DETAIL").text());
                $("[id*=tblDetailData]").append(row);
            });

            $('[id*=tblDetailData]').each(function () {
                $(this).find('td').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).text().trim() == "") {
                        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
                    };
                });
            });
        }
```

Aspx Page

```
                <table id="tblDetailData">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="gridheader_background" style="height: 30px; border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;">
                            <td>Date</td>
                            <td>Page</td>
                            <td>Action</td>
                            <td>Update By</td>
                            <td>Field</td>
                            <td>Detail</td>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
```